# jQuery selectable options slider

Tags: jquery, html, button, slider

I have two DIVs in my page that I want to show in the same area, and I want to have 1 button per option, and when clicking the buttons, have the DIVs slide to the correct DIV.

[This is what I want to achieve](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/partners/#marketplace).

There are three buttons on top, "Overview", "For Operators and Manufacturers" and "For Developers", and when you click on the button, you go to the specific DIV having the buttons still on top, to go back and forth where you want to.

Comment: Showing examples of code you have attempted will increase the likelihood of a response.

Answer (score 0):

Choose any of carousel library from the web (I have used [Bootstrap carousel](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel) before).

Add an event listener to each button such that clicking each button makes the carousel show a specific page you want.